# Pre-defined, special purpose system environment variables for Node/NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

Are there any special-purpose variables that I can pre-define for Node?

I've noticed that the in Windows, system environment variables *are* available to Node, like `%PATH%`, `%OS%`, and others.  You can define your own too, and they are all available via `process.env.your_var_name`.

In a lot of the documentation I've been reading, there are references to things like `PORT`, `ENV`, `NODE_PATH`, `DEBUG`, etc.

Are these "special" to Node itself, or are these just variables I can name & define on my own in the OS?

Answer (score 1):

`%PATH%`, `%OS%` are system environment variables and not specific to node. You can access them from the command line also.

Other environment variables like `PORT`, `ENV` are defined in a `.env` file to store credentials related to hosting and database.

You can create a `.env` file in the base directory of your project and store your own environment variables and access it using `dotenv` package.

More about environment variables:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/heres-how-you-can-actually-use-node-environment-variables-8fdf98f53a0a/

Comment: Are you aware of any special-purpose, "known" variables that Node/NPM is explicitly looking for, or expects?  Is there a master list of common or universal vars that can be defined?